# How to customize the reserved width for each level of a categorical variable on x-axis [ggplot2]

Tags: r, ggplot2, categorical-data, x-axis

Now I use the following codes to make a figure:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_simu <- tibble(
  Var1 = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  Var2 = c("P", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"),
  value = c(5, 10, 6, 4.5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2.4)
)

ggplot(df_simu, aes(x=Var1, y=value, fill=Var2, group=Var2))+
  geom_col(position=position_dodge2(preserve = "single", padding=0))
```

The resulting figure is
[image]

What I should do to reduce (or customize) the reserved space for `A`, i.e., remove the "black" areas in the following figure?
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK there is no easy option to achieve that. But if a hacky solution is an option for you then you could achieve your desired result with the good old "facets that don't look like facets trick". This time with some additional support from the `ggh4x` package to get the axis ticks right.

Basically this involves to use `facet_grid` which via the `space` argument makes it possible to get rid of the the empty space. To this end facet by `Var1` and map `Var2` on `x`. The rest is styling to get rid of the facet look and the axis labels (which now show categories of `Var2`). Moreover, to place the axis ticks at the right positions I first convert `Var2` to a numeric which allows to use a continuous scale and use `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` which allows to specify the scale and ticks separately for each facet:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggh4x)

df_simu <- data.frame(
  Var1 = c("A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
  Var2 = c("P", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"),
  value = c(5, 10, 6, 4.5, 3, 5, 5, 4, 2.4)
)

ggplot(df_simu, aes(x = as.numeric(factor(Var2)), y = value, fill = Var2)) +
  geom_col(width = 1) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Var1, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x", switch = "x") +
  ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales(
    list(
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1, expand = c(0, .3)),
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = 3.5, expand = c(0, .3)),
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = 3.5, expand = c(0, .3))
    )
  ) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), strip.background.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt"), strip.placement = "outside")
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! This is really helpful, especially the `ggh4x::facetted_pos_scales` and `panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "pt")`.